# My delete method isn't working (Android)

Tags: php, android, json

I have created a database using php and connected to android and now my method for deleting a row in table isn't working. And i'm using JSON for populating my list here. Here is my code, if anyone could help me:

**Activity with list of all items:**

```
public class QuestsFragment extends Fragment {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_quests = "http://192.168.0.17:8081/geomondo/get_all_quests.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_QUESTS = "quests";
private static final String TAG_QID = "qid";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_DISTRICT = "district";
private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";

private ListView listView;

// quests JSONArray
JSONArray quests = null;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quests, container, false);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    questsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String send_qid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            String send_title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                    .getText().toString();
            String send_description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc))
                    .getText().toString();
            String send_district = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.district))
                    .getText().toString();
            String send_code = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code))
                    .getText().toString();
            Intent send_values = new Intent(getActivity(), QuestsSingleActivity.class);
            send_values.putExtra(TAG_QID, send_qid);
            send_values.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, send_title);
            send_values.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, send_description);
            send_values.putExtra(TAG_DISTRICT, send_district);
            send_values.putExtra(TAG_CODE, send_code);
            startActivity(send_values);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_in_out);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(send_values, 100);
        }
    });

    // Loading quests in Background Thread
    new LoadAllQuests().execute();

    return rootView;
}

// Response from Edit Quest Activity
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }

}
/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all quest by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllQuests extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading quests. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All quests from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_quests, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Quests: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Quests
                quests = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTS);

                // looping through All Quests
                for (int i = 0; i < quests.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = null;
                    try {
                        c = quests.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_QID);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String district = c.getString(TAG_DISTRICT);
                    String code = c.getString(TAG_CODE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_QID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_DISTRICT, district);
                    map.put(TAG_CODE, code);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    questsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Quest Single Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        QuestsSingleActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // here you check the value of getActivity() and break up if needed
        if(getActivity() == null)
            return;
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), questsList,
                        R.layout.quests_row, new String[]{TAG_QID,
                        TAG_TITLE, TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_DISTRICT, TAG_CODE},
                        new int[]{R.id.qid, R.id.title, R.id.desc, R.id.district, R.id.code});
                // updating listview
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

**Activity with deleting method:**

```
public class QuestsSingleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText inputCode;
private Button submit;
private ImageView markImage;

String qid;

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_quest = "http://192.168.0.17:8081/geomondo/delete_quest.php";

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_QUEST = "quest";
private static final String TAG_QID = "qid";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";

private TextView description_quest, code_quest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
            .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
            .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
            .contentLayout(R.layout.quests_single_activity);
    setContentView(helper.createView(this));
    setTitle(intent.getStringExtra(TAG_TITLE));
    helper.initActionBar(this);

    // Locate ImageView
    markImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mark_single);
    // Locate EditText for Code Input
    inputCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCode);
    // Locate TextView for DESCRIPTION OF QUEST
    description_quest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc_single);
    // Locate TextView for CODE OF QUEST
    code_quest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_single);
    // Get values from previous Activity
    description_quest.setText(intent.getStringExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

    // Locate Button
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitCode);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quest_single_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.point_getting:
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_back, R.anim.slide_out_back);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    checkCodeQuest();
}

private void checkCodeQuest(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (!Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(TAG_CODE), inputCode.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The Code is Incorect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        new DeleteQuest().execute();
        startActivity(new Intent(QuestsSingleActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_back, R.anim.slide_out_back);
        markImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_tick);
    }
}
/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Quest
 * */
class DeleteQuest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuestsSingleActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Quest...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting quest
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qid", qid));

            // getting quest details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_quest, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Quest", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // quest successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about quest deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

If i need to put more code, for php files, just let me know. I would appricieate some help here.

Comment: What is the response for delete request?

Comment: in method checkCodeQuest. By the way, that method is finishing and returning to the previous activity, but there when i'm getting again list, there is still one row. Nothing is deleted.

Comment: Did u call notifyDataSet() changed after deleting the item?

Comment: Where should i call adapter.notifyDataSet()?

Comment: Check whether your json response for delete is success.If yes, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update your ListView